# java access subclass in superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have my code somewhat like this

```
class A
{
   int a;
   A()
   {
     //Here I want to print B or C
     System.out.println("Enter the value of a");
     a= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
   }
}
class B extends A
{
    int b;
    B()
    {
         //Here i can't write print B
         super();
         System.out.println("Enter the value of b");
         b= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
     }
   }
}
class C extends A
{
    int c;
    C()
    {
         //Here i can't write print C
         super();
         System.out.println("Enter the value of C");
         c= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
     }
 }
```

//my main function

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     B b1= new B();
     C c1=new C();
//Some other code
//.....
    C c2= new C();
    C c3= new C();
    B b2= new B();
}
```

In the output i am expecting it to tell whether it is B or C before it asks for the input it not good to add it in main I believe So how can I do that with constructor is it possible?

```
//Output somewhat like this
Enter values of class B
Enter the value of a
10
Enter the value of b
20
Enter values of class B
Enter the value of a
10
Enter the value of C
25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use java.lang.Class object to find class name at runtime.

Modify your class A as:

```
class A {
    int a;

    A() {
        // Here I want to print B or C
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("Enter the value of a");
        a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    }
}
```

When you instantiate B it will call super constructor of class A and prints B as name of class

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then one possible solution, pass a `String` to the constructor in `A`. Like,

```
class A
{
   int a;
   A(String msg)
   {
     System.out.printf("Enter the value of %s%n", msg);
     a= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
   }
}
```

And then use `super("B a");` and `super("C a");` respectively. But I would suggest you extract this kind of method to a utility method, I would not *personally* prompt for user input in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Create a protected variable in A, then you can override the value in its subclasses, B or C.

```
class A
{
   int a;
   protected String type;
   A()
   {
     type = "Class A"
     a= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
   }
}

class B extends A
{
    int b;
    B()
    {
         type = "Class B"; 
         b= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give up any idea of using the constructors to perform input/output.  It will never work they way you'd like.  Here's something that will:

```
public class Main {
    static class A {
        int a;
        public A(int a){
            this.a = a;
        }
    }

    static class B extends A {
        int b;
        public B(int a, int b) {
            super(a);
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    static class C extends B {
        int c;
        public C(int a, int b, int c){
            super(a,b);
            this.c = c;
        }
    }

    static B getB (Scanner sc){
        System.out.println("Enter values of class B...");
        System.out.println("Enter value of a:");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter value of b:");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        return new B(a, b);
    }


    static C getC (Scanner sc){
        System.out.println("Enter values of class C...");
        System.out.println("Enter value of a:");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter value of b:");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter value of c:");
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        return new C(a, b, c);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        B b1= getB(sc);
        C c1=getC(sc);
        //Some other code
     //.....
        C c2= getC(sc);
        C c3= getC(sc);
        B b2= getB(sc);
    }    
}
```